# What is source_column argument in csv loader?

Tags: python, nlp, language-model, csv

In [this tutorial](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/csv), what is the purpose of source_column argument? Does it act like a primary key in Databases? Thanks in advance.

```
loader = CSVLoader(file_path="./example_data/mlb_teams_2012.csv", source_column="Team")
data = loader.load()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Langchain can gather information from multiple places and track the source of information that is used to answer a query. Source in this context refers to the source of information within the csv file: if not specified the source defaults to the path of the csv file, but you can also feed in a csv file that has a column that specifies sources for each row.

from:  https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/document_loaders/langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader.CSVLoader.html

"The source for each document loaded from csv is set to the value of the file_path argument for all documents by default. You can override this by setting the source_column argument to the name of a column in the CSV file. The source of each document will then be set to the value of the column with the name specified in source_column."

For example, this csv has a column that contains paths to the original source information, so passing that column in as source would make sense.
[image]

You can see where this gets used in here: https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/weaviate#question-answering-with-sources - the sources are returned from queries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you could discuss with some examples that would be helpful. For example what is the difference if I choose col1 to be the source vs col2?

Comment: It's not col1 vs. col2 really, it's whether your csv contains a column that points back to the source of the information or not. If your csv has such a column, then that should be used, if it doesn't, then defaulting to the csv file path is reasonable. I'll add an image if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

We use the `source_column` argument to specify a source for the document created from each row. Otherwise `file_path` will be used as the source for all documents created from the `CSV` file.

This is useful when using documents loaded from `CSV` files for chains that answer questions using sources
[tutorial](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/csv)

Comment: This is the answer given by the [tutorial](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/csv). You should add it to your answer so OP understands where this is coming from.

Comment: Just did, thank you.